# Can you use advance() in a string::iterator in C++?

Tags: c++, string, iterator

```
        for( string::iterator it = line.begin(); it != line.end(); it++ )
        {
            advance( it, 1 );
        }
```

I get a segmentation fault. I'm trying to get the next value in the iterator so that I can compare it to  a hexadecimal.

Comment: You sure can. You still aren't allowed to go beyond `end()`, though.

Comment: Try a string with one more or one fewer characters, and you probably won't get a segfault.

Comment: I think you want to use [`std::adjacent_find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find)

Comment: You may want to go to one before `line.end()`.

Comment: Look at the docs: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance `std::advance` is not what you want to use...

Comment: I wouldn't use advance() for this but since you asked could you do it I provided a solution below.

Comment: Just curious, is a string iterator just an array of strings? That would explain how it = it + 1 works because it just moves it forward by the size of a pointer.

Comment: If it = it + 1; really is the same thing as an advance why wouldn't you just substitute it into the for loop argument?

Comment: @CleoR: A string-iterator is just a RandomAccessIterator. Look at the concept and what it provides. (The simplest string-iterator would be a `char*` btw...) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags

Answer (score 2):

You sure can use `advance` there, but beware:

Unless you break the loop before you get too near to the end, or the length of the string is even, you will have a buffer-overrun and UB.

```
for( string::iterator it = line.begin(); it != line.end(); it++ )
{
    advance( it, 1 );
}
```

Is equivalent too:

```
for(auto it = line.begin(); it != line.end(); it += 2 )
{}
```

Because `advance(it, 1);` is equivalent to `++i;`.
See here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance

If you only want the next value, check for its existence with `it+1 != line.end()` and get it with `it[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may want to change it++ to ++it. I referenced this example case here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/begin/. I think that will advance the iterator for you, so I don't think you'll need both that and advance. Try something like
this,

```
string::iterator it = line.begin();
while(it != line.end()){
  //Do something with the iterator
  advance( it, 1 );
}
```

This is another reference that I found useful. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/advance/